# Fatal error: Call to a member function getOwner() on a non-object in my PHP code

Tags: php, oop

I'm writing a project to learn PHP. I have a DB class called DBController in which I'm calling the method 'getOwner()' while passing through a variable that returns an array. I also have a test.php page in which I mess around with and see if my classes work. I called the 'getOwner()' in my test.php page and it returns the array fine. But when I use my 'login.php' file, it gives me the error

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getOwner() on a non-object

I tried a few things in which I looked up but I don't know what's wrong.

Below are my classes, thank you for taking the time to help.

```
<?php
//var_dump($_POST['data']);
include('../model/DBController.php');

$dbController = new DBController();

$username = $_POST['data']['username'];
$password = $_POST['data']['password'];

if(!empty($username) || !empty($password)){

    // Getting the error here.
    $owner = $dbConntroller->getOwner($username);

    var_dump($owner);

    echo "Logged in";
} else {
    echo "Error";
}

?>
```

This class when calling 'getOwner()' works fine then...

```
<?php
include('controller/classes/Cow.php');
include('controller/classes/Owner.php');
include('model/DBController.php');

$dbController = new DBController();

$var = $dbController->getOwner("Eada");
var_dump($var);
?>
```

Comment: `$dbConntroller` <--- spelling.

Comment: Start to use an IDE like Netbeans, PHPStrom, you can choose what you like, to use autocompletition for your variable and method names.

Comment: You have typo in variable name. There is no such variable (dbConntroller) - that's the problem.

Comment: Okay now I feel really foolish. Couldn't see the extra N for the life of me. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not: $dbConntroller but $dbController with **only one n** . check what names you are using